# Google authentification error "no route match"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a problem, I follow this tutorial :https://richonrails.com/articles/google-authentication-in-ruby-on-rails.

I have done everything except `rails g controller home show` because I have already a static_pages controller and home.html.erb

So in my `route.rb` I have replace this line from the tutorial:

`resource :home, only: [:show] 
root to: "home#show"`

by

`resource :static_pages, only: [:home]
root to: 'static_pages#home'`

but when I click on the link after I've launched the server (localhost) I have this error:

`No route matches [GET] "/auth/google_oauth2"`

Do you have any idea about this problem? Hope you could help me.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT : My route.rb code

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'sessions/create'
  get 'sessions/destroy'
  get 'sessions/new'
  get 'users/new'

  root             'static_pages#home'
  get 'help'    => 'static_pages#help'
  get 'about'   => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'signup'  => 'users#new'
  get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :users
end
GoogleAuthExample::Application.routes.draw do
  get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
  get 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
  get 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'

  resources :sessions, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resource :static_pages, only: [:home]

  root to: 'static_pages#home'
end
```

Comment: Are you using `gem 'devise'` with `gem "omniauth-google-oauth2"`?

Comment: non i'm not using "devise" why?

Comment: please refer this link for google auth.
 https://deepakrip007.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/google-integration-using-devise-and-omniauth-in-rails-app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It work! I do that with devise. but just dont forget to install "mongoid" gem in order to set up devise (that took me lot of time to determine mogoid was missing).

Thank you all!